# Adding a new node to end of a linked list using pointers and function in C

Tags: c

I'm very new to the linked list and trying to add a new node to the end of one. I'm using a header file and function for this and here is my functions. I'm trying to use customerAdd and printAllCustomers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "salesautomation.h"

int categoryFilter(char category[]){
    
    int a;
    
    if(strcmp(category,"1")==0 || strcmp(category,"Sale") == 0 || strcmp(category,"sale") == 0){
        a = 1;
    }
    
    else if((strcmp(category,"2")==0) || (strcmp(category,"Customer Informations") == 0) || (strcmp(category,"Customer informations") == 0) || (strcmp(category, "customer informations") == 0) || strcmp(category,"customer Informations") == 0){
        a = 2;
    }
    
    else if(strcmp(category,"3")==0 || strcmp(category,"Product Informations") == 0 || strcmp(category,"Product informations") == 0 || strcmp(category, "product informations") == 0 || strcmp(category,"product Informations") == 0){
        a = 3;
    }
    
    else if(strcmp(category,"4")==0 || strcmp(category,"Customer Analysis") == 0 || strcmp(category,"Customer analysis") == 0 || strcmp(category, "customer analysis") == 0 || strcmp(category,"customer Analysis") == 0){
        a = 4;
    }
    
    else if(strcmp(category,"5")==0 || strcmp(category,"Product Analysis") == 0 || strcmp(category,"Product analysis") == 0 || strcmp(category, "product analysis") == 0 || strcmp(category,"product Analysis") == 0){
        a = 5;
    }
    
    else if(strcmp(category,"6")==0 || strcmp(category,"Exit") == 0 || strcmp(category,"exit") == 0){
        a = 6;
    }
    else{
        a = 0;
    }
    
    return a;
}

int customerChecker(char name[]){
    return 0;
}

void customerAdd(Customer **N01){
    Customer *newCustomer;
    newCustomer = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    Customer *last = *N01;
    
    printf("Customer ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &newCustomer->ID);
    printf("%d\n", newCustomer->ID);
    printf("Customer Name: ");
    getchar();// If i don't put this here, gets scans \n when user hits enter. So i put this here to save \n to nowhere
    gets(newCustomer->name);
    printf("%s\n",newCustomer->name);
    printf("Customer Type (1 for corporate, 2 for individual): ");
    scanf("%d",&newCustomer->type);
    printf("%d\n",newCustomer->type);
    printf("Customer x coordinate: ");
    scanf("%lf",&newCustomer->coordX);
    printf("%lf\n",newCustomer->coordX);
    printf("Customer y coordinate: ");
    scanf("%lf",&newCustomer->coordY);
    printf("%lf\n",newCustomer->coordY);
    newCustomer->nextCustomer = NULL;
    
    if(*N01 == NULL){
        *N01 = newCustomer;
    }
    else{
        while(last->nextCustomer != NULL){
            last = last->nextCustomer;
        }
        last->nextCustomer = newCustomer;
    }
    
}

void printAllCustomers(Customer *N01){
    int i=1;
    printf("\n-All customers in the system-\n\n");
    while(N01 != NULL){
        printf("%d-)%s\n",i,N01->name);
        N01 = N01->nextCustomer;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("-------------------\n\n");
}

void printCustomerType(Customer *N01, int type){
    int i=1;
    if(type == 1){
        printf("\n-All corporate customers in the system-\n\n");
        while(N01 != NULL){
            if(N01->type == 1){
                printf("%d-%s\n",i,N01->name);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            N01 = N01->nextCustomer;
        }
    }
    else if(type == 2){
        printf("\n-All individual customers in the system-\n\n");
        while(N01 != NULL){
            if(N01->type == 2){
                printf("%d-)%s\n",i,N01->name);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            N01 = N01->nextCustomer;
        }
    }
}

void printCustomer(Customer *N01, char name[]){
    while(N01 != NULL){
        if(strcmp(N01->name,name) == 0){
            printf("\nCustomer ID: %d\nCustomer name: %s\nCustomer x coordinate: %lf\nCustomer y coordinate: %lf\n\n",N01->ID,N01->name,N01->coordX,N01->coordY);
        }
        N01 = N01->nextCustomer;
    }
}
```

And here is where and how i call the function. It's in Category 2 and subcategory 4. After i run the function, i'm trying to print all of them in Category 2 and subcategory 1. It doesn't appear there

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "salesautomation.h"

int main(){
    int exit = 0;
    while(exit == 0){
    // PREDEFINED CUSTOMERS
    Customer *N01;
    Customer *N02;
    Customer *N03;
    
    N01 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    N02 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    N03 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    
    N01->ID = 1;
    strcpy(N01->name,"Kutay Sahlankaya");
    N01->type = 2;
    N01->coordX = 3;
    N01->coordY = 4;
    N01->nextCustomer = N02;
    
    N02->ID = 2;
    strcpy(N02->name,"Servet Sahlankaya");
    N02->type = 1;
    N02->coordX = 6;
    N02->coordY = 8;
    N02->nextCustomer = N03;
    
    N03->ID = 3;
    strcpy(N03->name,"Tuba Gozel");
    N03->type = 1;
    N03->coordX = 20;
    N03->coordY = 15;
    N03->nextCustomer = NULL;
    
    ////////////////////////////
    printf("----------- SALES AUTOMATION PROGRAM -----------\n\n");
    
    char category[25];
    int categoryNum=0, check1=0;
    categoryNum = 0;
    check1 = 0;
    strcpy(category,"");
    while(check1 == 0){
    printf("Please choose the category that you want to use from below\n\n");
    printf("1- Sale\n2- Customer Informations\n3- Product Informations\n4- Customer Analysis\n5- Product Analysis\n6- Exit\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &category);
    
    categoryNum = categoryFilter(category);
        if(categoryNum == 0){
            printf("\n[ERROR]- Please read and type in carefully!\n\n");
        }
        else{
            check1 = 1;
        }
    }
    // CATEGORY 1
    if(categoryNum == 1){
        char cat1_name[20];
        printf("\nCustomer name : ");
        scanf("%s",&cat1_name);
        if(customerChecker(cat1_name) == 0){
            int check2 = 0;
            while(check2 == 0){
                char checker;
                printf("\nEntered customer name is not recognized, do you want to add a new customer?(Y\\N)\n");
                scanf("%c", &checker);
                if(checker == 'Y'){
                    customerAdd(&N01);
                    check2 = 1;
                }
                else if(checker == 'N'){
                    printf("\nTerminating sale process...\n");
                    check2 = 1;
                }
                else{
                    printf("[ERROR]- Please enter your answer as given.\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //CATEGORY 2
    else if(categoryNum == 2){
        int subcategory2;
        printf("\n-Customer Informations-\n\nPlease choose the category that you want to use from below. Please use category numbers.\n\n1-All Customers\n2-According to the customer type\n3-Single Customer\n4-Add Customer\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &subcategory2);
        if(subcategory2 == 1){
            printAllCustomers(N01);
        }
        else if(subcategory2 == 2){
            int cust_type;
            printf("Which customer type do you want to see? Please use numbers\n1-Individual\n2-Corporate\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&cust_type);
            printCustomerType(N01,cust_type);
        }
        else if(subcategory2 == 3){
            char junk;
            char cat2_name[30];
            printf("\nPlease enter the customer name in Fffff Sssss format : ");
            getchar(); // If i don't put this here, gets scans \n when user hits enter. So i put this here to save \n to nowhere
            gets(cat2_name);
            printCustomer(N01,cat2_name);        
        }
        else if(subcategory2 == 4){
            customerAdd(&N01);
        }
    }
    else if(categoryNum == 3){
        
    }
    else if(categoryNum == 4){
        
    }
    else if(categoryNum == 5){
        
    }
    else if(categoryNum == 6){
        printf("\n\nTerminating program...");
        return 0;
    }
    }
}
```

And here is the header file.

```
#ifndef saleautomation_h_
#define saleautomation_h_

struct Customer{
    int ID;
    char name[30];
    int type;
    double coordX;
    double coordY;
    struct Customer *nextCustomer;
};
typedef struct Customer Customer;
typedef Customer * CustomerPtr;

struct product{
    int ID;
    char name[20];
    int type;
    double price;
    struct product *nextproduct;
};
typedef struct product product;
typedef product * productptr;

struct sold{
    int ID;
    int billID;
    int customerID;
    int productID;
    int quantity;
    double cost;
    struct sold *nextsold;
};
typedef struct sold sold;
typedef sold * soldptr;

int categoryFilter(char category[]);
int customerChecker(char name[]);
void customerAdd(Customer **N01);
void printAllCustomers(Customer *N01);
void printCustomerType(Customer *N01, int type);
void printCustomer(Customer *N01, char name[]);

#endif
```

The function works and i write values that i want it to hold. The problem is, I can't add a new node globally. When I print the whole linked list, it doesn't appear at the and it prints only predefined nodes. I think it just adds it in this function but i want to make it globally in code and access it in main code. I've tried to use pointers and etc. but i couldn't manage to do it. Can you help me please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. What exactly means "I want to make it globally in code and access it in main code"? What exactly does not work with the code in the question? (What input do you use, what output/behavior do you actually get and what do you expect instead? Show the variants you tried without success and explain what problems you found

Comment: Code looks like it should add a node correctly.  Please show how you are calling it.

Comment: I've edited it and tried to be more understandable. Sorry if i couldn't again @Bodo

Comment: I've added it @stark

Comment: Your code snippets still aren't a [mre]. We cannot compile and run it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: *"I can't add a new node globally."* - maybe "how you're calling it" wasn't clear enough. We need enough code for **us** to copy/paste/compile/run *and* reproduce your problem. When you say "I can't add a new node globally." please understand we have no concept of what you actually mean. Pretend the only thing we know about your code, and thus your program and its architecture is exactly, and *only*, what you have shown here. Then, stop pretending; that's all we have to work with. A proper [mcve] is required if you want resolution to this. What you posted is (mostly) proper for list append.

Comment: [mre] means you at least show the definition of `Customer` and how your variable `N01` is defined and used.  You aren't being charged by the word! Go nuts with the copy and paste.

Comment: I've added all of the code. Sorry for not being clear. @Bodo

Comment: I've added all of the code. Sorry for not being clear. @WhozCraig

Comment: I've added all of the code. Sorry for not being clear. @stark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this:

```
    // PREDEFINED CUSTOMERS
    Customer *N01;
    Customer *N02;
    Customer *N03;

    N01 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    N02 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    N03 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));

    N01->ID = 1;
    strcpy(N01->name, "Kutay Sahlankaya");
    N01->type = 2;
    N01->coordX = 3;
    N01->coordY = 4;
    N01->nextCustomer = N02;

    N02->ID = 2;
    strcpy(N02->name, "Servet Sahlankaya");
    N02->type = 1;
    N02->coordX = 6;
    N02->coordY = 8;
    N02->nextCustomer = N03;

    N03->ID = 3;
    strcpy(N03->name, "Tuba Gozel");
    N03->type = 1;
    N03->coordX = 20;
    N03->coordY = 15;
    N03->nextCustomer = NULL;
```

is in the wrong place. You have it *inside* your while loop. As a result, after each operation two things happen:

1. The memory they point to (and anything you did on the last iteration) is leaked.
2. They're reset to their starting values (with new allocations) that will be summarily leaked after the next iteration.

Move *all* of that *above* the entrance to the while-loop in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    // PREDEFINED CUSTOMERS
    Customer *N01;
    Customer *N02;
    Customer *N03;

    N01 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    N02 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    N03 = malloc(sizeof(Customer));

    N01->ID = 1;
    strcpy(N01->name, "Kutay Sahlankaya");
    N01->type = 2;
    N01->coordX = 3;
    N01->coordY = 4;
    N01->nextCustomer = N02;

    N02->ID = 2;
    strcpy(N02->name, "Servet Sahlankaya");
    N02->type = 1;
    N02->coordX = 6;
    N02->coordY = 8;
    N02->nextCustomer = N03;

    N03->ID = 3;
    strcpy(N03->name, "Tuba Gozel");
    N03->type = 1;
    N03->coordX = 20;
    N03->coordY = 15;
    N03->nextCustomer = NULL;

    int exit = 0;
    while (exit == 0)
    {
        ////////////////////////////
        printf("----------- SALES AUTOMATION PROGRAM -----------\n\n");

...
```